# Flower doesn't display complete result string

Tags: python, celery, flower

I use flower to monitoring celery functions but if the result string is long, flower doesn't display all of it.

When I send request with python to flower, the result is the same, result is still not complete.

```
 {'Name': {21: {'state': 'open', 'reason': 'syn-ack', 'name': 'ftp', 'product': 'vsftpd', 'version': '2.3.4', 'extrainfo': '', 'conf': '10', 'cpe': 'cpe:/a:vsftpd:vsftpd:2.3.4'}, 22: {'state': 'open', 'reason': 'syn-ack', 'name': 'ssh', 'product': 'OpenSSH', 'version': '4.7p1 Debian 8ubuntu1', 'extrainfo': 'protocol 2.0', 'conf': '10', 'cpe': 'cpe:/o:linux:linux_kernel'}, 23: {'state': 'open', 'reason': 'syn-ack', 'name': 'telnet', 'product': 'Linux telnetd', 'version': '', 'extrainfo': '', 'conf': '10', 'cpe': 'cpe:/o:linux:linux_kernel'}, 25: {'state': 'open', 'reason': 'syn-ack', 'name': 'smtp', 'product': 'Postfix smtpd', 'version': '', 'extrainfo': '', 'conf': '10', 'cpe': 'cpe:/a:postfix:postfix'}, 53: {'state': 'open', 'reason': 'syn-ack', 'name': 'domain', 'product': 'ISC BIND', 'version': '9.4.2', 'extrainfo': '', 'conf': '10', 'cpe': 'cpe:/a:isc:bind:9.4.2', 'script': {...}}, 80: {'state': 'open', 'reason': 'syn-ack', 'name': 'http', 'product': 'Apache httpd', 'version': '2.2.8', 'extrainfo': '(Ubuntu...', ...}}}
```

**Update:**
I did what you said @sp1rs, I set resultrepr_maxsize very high number but json that I got still doesn't bring some parts such as 'script' . It still shows {...}. I can't copy-paste it here because too long but I can take a photo. You can see that 'script' key doesn't have the result. (3. line) ibb.co/G0YShMK

In addition to that, if I get the function result with get() function in the python shell, 'script' keys and values come safely but flower doesn't bring them. Any idea?

Comment: don't use images. Put it as text in question. And show your code. Downvote.

Comment: https://ibb.co/JvBySGK and https://ibb.co/yBsFFsK. Also, I will add the text.

Comment: So what is the question here? How to fix this? How to get the "full" result?

Comment: Yes, how to get full result? I didn't find anything in Flower docs.

Comment: You should modify the original message WITH the question, so people know what you want...

Answer (score 1):

Flower is just the dashboard and will display what celery gives to it. For performance issue celery limit the length of task result.

https://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/reference/celery.app.task.html#celery.app.task.Task.resultrepr_maxsize

by default `resultrepr_maxsize = 1024`.
Change the `resultrepr_maxsize` value to increase the length of your final result.

Comment: I did what you said, I set resultrepr_maxsize very high number but json that I got still doesn't bring some parts such as 'script' . It still shows {...}. I can't copy-paste it here because too long but I can take a photo. You can see that 'script' key doesn't have the result. (3. line) https://ibb.co/G0YShMK

Comment: In addition to that, if I get the function result with get() function in the python shell, 'script' keys and values come safely but flower doesn't bring them. Any idea?

Comment: It is the same story... Flower does not want to spam with enormous results. And it DOES make sense!

Comment: So how can I get the full result using flower api?